# Result Source Query do not include allitems dispform editform

Tags: search, search-results

I am creating a result source and in the query I want to add something so it removes all of the sites like DispForm, Editform, allitems. How can I do this in the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a couple places, it makes the most sense to me to include these as search exclusion rules within CA. This helps trim down your index, making it more relavent. This would be done by creating rules that exclude content like `*://*allitems.aspx*`.
[image]

If you are doing this on a search results page, you'd do it like Steve Mann demonstrates in this blog article, http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-search-removing-junk.html

Create 3 property filters based on the filename not contatind dispform, editform, and allitems.